# Passing a HOC component to all your other routes in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, session-timeout

I have a HOC component that uses IdleTimer.  I am creating a idle timeout feature to logout the user after a certain time in my react, redux application.  I am having a hard time passing this over to my other routes.  What would be the best way to approach this?

HOC (IdleTimer)

```
import IdleTimer from "react-idle-timer";
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function HOC (AutoLogoutComponent) {
 return class extends Component{
      idleTimer;

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
              timeout:      1000*5,
              showModal:    false,
              userLoggedIn: false,
              isTimedOut:   false
          };

          this.idleTimer = null;
          this.onAction = this._onAction.bind(this);
          this.onActive = this._onActive.bind(this);
          this.onIdle = this._onIdle.bind(this);

      }

      _onAction(e){
          console.log('User did something', e);
          this.setState({isTimedOut: false})
      }

      _onActive(e){
          console.log('user is active', e);
          this.setState({isTimedOut: false})
      }

      _onIdle(e){
          console.log('user is idle', e);
          const isTimedOut = this.state.isTimedOut;
          if (isTimedOut){
              this.props.history.push('/')
          }else {
              this.setState({showModal: true});
              this.idleTimer.reset();
              this.setState({isTimedOut: true})
          }
      }

    render() {
        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <IdleTimer
                    ref={ref => {this.idleTimer = ref}}
                    element={document}
                    onActive={this.onActive}
                    onIdle={this.onIdle}
                    onAction={this.onAction}
                    debounce={250}
                    timeout={this.state.timeout} />

                    <div className="">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route
                               exact path={`${match.path}/sales-analysis/dashboard`}
                                render={(props) => <DefaultLayout {...props} /> }/>
                            />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

 }
}
    HOC.propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
```

my Index.js file where my routes are.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.props.store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<div />} persistor={this.props.persistor}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div id="browserRouter">
              <Route exact path="/" component={LoginContainer} key="login" />
              <Route
                path="/change-password"
                component={LoginContainer}
                key="change-password"
              />
              <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} key="logout" />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/sales-analysis/dashboard"
                component={HOC(DashboardContainer)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/sales-analysissbfhghgb"
                component={HOC(ActiveClientsContainer)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/sales-analysis/sbs5dygkjgkh"
                component={HOC(ActivityReportsContainer)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/sales-analysis/bbebshyfyfu"
                component={HOC(SegmentsContainer)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout path="/adfserv" component={ProspectsContainer} />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/preferences/general"
                component={HOC(PreferenceGeneral)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/preferences/sdfgsverv"
                component={HOC(PreferenceAccountManager)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/preferences/sdvs3esdfvsd"
                component={HOC(PreferenceFlexFields)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/preferences/osbrddfsf"
                component={HOC(PreferenceOEMManager)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/preferences/users"
                component={HOC(PreferenceUsers)}
              />
              <DefaultLayout
                path="/preferences/group-users"
                component={HOC(PreferenceGroupUsers)}
              />
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
AppEntry = HOC(AppEntry);
```

store

```
function configureStore() {
  let store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(
        //onSuccessMiddleware, may not need this...
        axiosMiddleware(API, apiOptions),
        thunk,
        notificationMiddleware
      )
    )
  );
  let persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `HOC(SegmentsContainer)`, you're generally trying to wrap your `SegmentsContainer` with some new code, right?

And in the context of your HOC, `function HOC (AutoLogoutComponent)`, your `SegmentsContainer` ends up being named `AutoLogoutComponent`.

Now, I'm not an expert on Higher Order Components, but generally speaking, inside your HOC you'd want to actually render your `AutoLogoutComponent` somewhere. Otherwise, it seems to me that you're accepting it as an argument and then throwing it away. And that's what it looks like you're doing here. You're not using that argument in your render function anywhere.

[edit] look at the example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). The official docs. They've got a higher order component, `function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectData)`, and they render `WrappedComponent` in their render function